# Locating a specific position on the page

Tags: nodes

I want to provide a clickable link on drupal such that it easily locates the position of the content in a page. e.g http://asblab.mie.utoronto.ca/people , I want to have a link , that automatically scrolls this page to locate "Past lab member" without requiring me to create a new node. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you put whatever you want in a div or span with an id, you can then use that id for an anchor.  For example, `<a href="http://asblab.mie.utoronto.ca/people#content-inner">GO HERE</a>` will [GO HERE](http://asblab.mie.utoronto.ca/people#content-inner)

Comment: @meekahu Also check out this http://help.typepad.com/anchor-tags.html for more info if needed.